# The compiled Intel compiler XE 19 not working at Windows 10 AMD Ryzen with error 0xc000007b using /Qparallel

Tags: fortran, intel, intel-fortran, amd-processor

I tried to compile Dave Frank's TEST_FPU benchmark that now zipped into polyhedron benchmark using Intel Parallel XE Fortran 19.0 Update 1 on Windows 10 1909.

TEST_FPU2.f90 was downloaded from Polyhedron https://www.fortran.uk/pb11.zip
the old one on http://www.lps.ens.fr/~dominiq/polyhedron/test_fpu.f90
the new one at polyhedron site.

I tried some switches including /O2 and /O3 also /Qparallel compiled on Intel workstation :

alt 1: ifort /O2 test_fpu2.f90 /link /stack:64000000

alt 2: ifort /O3 test_fpu2.f90 /link /stack:64000000

alt 3: ifort /O3 /Qparallel test_fpu2.f90 /link /stack:64000000

Both /O2 /O3 alt1 and alt 2 works fine.while the alt 3 : auto parallel that enhance via multi threading got error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00000b7) on windows 10 AMD Ryzen workstation and notebook; Ryzen 3600 and Ryzen 2700U .

Meanwhile all intel notebook and workstation 9th gen and 8th gen works great with all alternatives but need file libiomp5md.dll, and no need redistributable libraries installed.

In the AMD workstation we tried using redistributable https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributable-libraries-for-intel-c-and-fortran-2019-compilers-for-windows

After redistributable was installed at AMD machine, the program were suddenly off.

So with auto parallel, the compiled program not working at AMD.
Any clue?

Edited: with auto parallel, compiled not working not without autoparallel

Comment: The usual cause for this particular error is that Windows is unable to map all of the various fixed memory requirements, including static code and data, and the stack. Why auto-parallel should matter, I don't know. Do I understand correctly that installing the redistributables  changed the behavior. I very much doubt the processor brand has any relation to this.

Comment: Thank you steve for years contributing fortran development. It is possible to make it parallel manually instead auto parallel in ifort? And /Qopenmp also make same error 0xc00000b7

Comment: You can certainly use OpenMP to add "directed parallelism" to an application. I don't have personal experience doing this. Just adding /Qopenmp doesn't make things parallel - it tells the compiler you want to use OpenMP and makes all procedures recursive by default. The error you got is what I put in my comment above - Windows is unable to honor all of the requests for where parts of the program get mapped into memory.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved at Intel Parallel XE 2020. 
The problem was exist in Parallel XE 2019 Update 2.
Meanwhile the other, 2019 Update 3 to Update 5 are not checked yet.